# Show matrix A is invertible if and only if $a_0 \neq 0$ with $A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+....+a_1A+a_0I=O$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be a real square matrix en let $I$ be the identity matrix with the same size. Let $n>0$ be the smallest natural number for which there exist  $a_0,a_1,...a_{n-1} \in {R}$ such that $A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+....+a_1A+a_0I=O$.

Show that A is invertible if and only if $a_0\neq0 $.

So i need to proof

1. $A$ invertible $\rightarrow$$a_0 \neq 0$
2. $a_0 \neq0 \rightarrow$ $A$ invertible

I don't really know where to start with 1, and with 2 I tried to prove it with a contradiction but I don't think it's right either.

Comment: I think your problem statement is a bit unclear.  It does sound like you have to prove the existence of $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ with $a_0\neq 0$ in the case where $A$ is invertible.  I don't see any answer talking about it.  However, it is not difficult.

Comment: @Batominovski my textbook states i don't have to prove the existence of those. The answers answered my question perfectly

Comment: Note that if degree $n$ is "the smallest natural number" possible, then you are asking about how the minimal polynomial for $A$ will look.  See the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1A+a_0I=0\implies a_0I=-\left(A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+\ldots a_1A\right)\implies$$

$$a_0I=A\;\overbrace{\left(-A^{n-1}-a_{n-1}A^{n-2}-\ldots-a_1I\right)}^{=B}$$

Now, observe that $\;B\;$ is an excellent candidate to *almost* be $\;A^{-1}\;$ , but this will happen iff ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix. If $a_0 = 0$ then
$$A^n + a_{n-1}A^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1A = O$$
but then
$$A^{n-1} + a_{n-2}A^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1I = A^{-1}(A^n + a_{n-1}A^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1A) = O$$

but that contradicts the assumption that $n$ was minimal. Therefore $a_0$ must be nonzero.

Conversely, if $a_0\neq 0$ then

$$\dfrac{-1}{a_0}(A^{n-1} + a_{n-2}A^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1I)A = I$$

so $$\dfrac{-1}{a_0}(A^{n-1} + a_{n-2}A^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1I) = A^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you! But why does the $a_{n-1}$ change in to$ a_{n-2}$ and not the $A^{n-1} $into$ A^{n-2}$?

Comment: @Zoey nothing changed into anything, I just either multiplied by $A^{-1}$ or extracted a common factor $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Forward part $A$ is invertible implies $a_0\neq 0$. Lets look at the contrapositive. If $a_0=0$ then
$$A(A^{n-1}+a_{n-1}A^{n-2}+...+a_1I)=0$$
Now if A is invertible then $A^{n-1}+a_{n-1}A^{n-2}+...+a_1I=0$ which contradicts the fact that n is the smallest number which annihilates A.
Backward implication if $a\neq 0$ then we can find the inverse of $A$ as $\frac{-1}{a_0}(A^{n-1}+a_{n-1}A^{n-2}+...+a_1I)$